# How to retrieve variable from parent table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a table(`TableA`), that has another table in it(`TableB`). I want to retrieve a variable that is located in `TableA` from within `TableB`. How would I go about doing this? I have tried:

```
tableA = {
testA = 5;

    tableB = {
        testB = tableA.testA + 1; 
    };

}

print(tableA.tableB.testB)
```

but get an error from within `tableB` that states that `tableA` doesn't exist.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the semicolons to terminate a statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tableA.testA` does not exist until the definition of `tableA` is complete.

You need to do `tableA.tableB.testB = tableA.testA + 1` after  `tableA` is complete.